# How can I move blocks around in Magento 1.x layout?

Tags: layout, magento-1

[image]

I'm trying to move the highlighted `div` right after the header page div. I'm not sure how I can do this - can someone explain how?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, I'd appreciate if you'd consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. It sounds like you're not very familiar with Magento's frontend system, so I'll refer you to another answer that I wrote that explains it in detail: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135744/5134.

Now, to apply the principles there to your problem, you should use the `unsetChild` and `insert` methods to remove the block in one place, and insert it in another. I recommend doing this in your theme's `local.xml` file, although if this is a module-specific customization, you may want to put it in a layout file specific to your module.

Here's an example of how to remove the block and reinsert it:

```
<layout>
    <reference name="the_parent_block_of_the_main_container_block">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <alias>the_alias_of_the_main_container_block</alias>
        </action
    </reference>
    <reference name="the_parent_of_the_header">
        <action method="insert">
            <blockName>name_of_the_main_container_block</blockName>
        </action>
    </reference>
</layout>
```