# Add text fields to Custom shipping Method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I have created a custom shipping method in magento 1.9.1 thanks to this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747).

That part was easy, Now I want to add a couple of text inputs (one is a shipping carrier and the other is an account no for that carrier) and a dropdown (showing multiple shipping plans) to this shipping method.
How do I display them in the frontend with this shipping method?
Do I do save this additional data in a new table or can I save them in the order?

What I need is some steps, guidance, not functional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

To display them, you'll need to use a custom block and template, and a solid grasp of the Magento frontend system. If you feel lacking in that area, read this: [Editing an Existing Theme - Locating the XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135728/editing-an-existing-theme-locating-the-xml/135744#135744).

To process the data from those fields, you'll probably have to override something in the backend. You may be able to add them to an already submitted from on the frontend, and override a controller or models, or you may have to create your own controller.

You can save them on the order table by adding additional columns to the table, and that's the approach I'd recommend, as opposed to adding more tables. Storing similar sets of data in the same place is my preference.

Good luck, and let me know if you have any questions in the comments below.

Comment: can you please take a look at this query of mine? [shipping&handling](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148809/shipping-and-handling-information)

Comment: @umair.ashfr thanks for accepting my answer! I've answered your other question; if that solves your problem, would you accept it, as well?