# shipping and handling information

Tags: magento-1.9

I have successfully created a custom shipping method using this [tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/07/magento-advanced-shipping-method-development/?facebook=1). I am unable to display this information in the admin panel correctly. This is my code just like the one in above tutorial

```
class Excellence_Pickup_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{
public function getShippingDescription(){
    $desc = parent::getShippingDescription();
   // print_r($desc);
    $pickupObject = $this->getPickupObject();
    if($pickupObject){
        $desc.= '\r\nShipping Carrier:'.$pickupObject->getShp_carrier();
        $desc.= '\r\nShipping Carrier:'.$pickupObject->getAccountno();
        $desc.= '\r\nShipping Carrier:'.$pickupObject->getShp_method();
    }

    return $desc;
}

}
```

As you can see i am using "\r\n", i also have tried using "br" tags but they also appear as it is in the admin panel as shown in the image below[image: Shipping & Handling Information admin panel].

What is the way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is being filtered in the template:

```
//From sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml

<?php if ($_order->getShippingDescription()): ?>
    <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?></strong>

//...
```

To fix this, override the template and remove the call to `escapeHtml()`. That should fix it.

Please let me know if you have any questions!